# The dimension of the intersection of two matrices ranges

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I’d like to ask the following:
Considering the matrices $A$ and $B$, both with the dimensions $ n \times m$. The ranges are $R(A)$ and $R(B)$.
I would like to find:

$$
D= \dim( R(A)  \cap  R(B))
$$

expressed in the orthonormal basis of the intersection subspace.
Can you help me?

I sincerely thank you! :)

All the best

GoodSpirit

Comment: A dimension is not expressed with respect to a basis. This question has no general answer, the dimension of the intersection can be anything from $0$ to $n$.

Comment: @GoodSpirit Both of those links will show you how to find a basis for the intersection.  Then you can run Graham-Schmidt to get an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @Jim Very minor comment: it's Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Thank you Jim , that's it!!! all the best GoodSpirit